# Moving to next Page in Data Report

Tags: vb6, report

I am trying to make a data report in VB6 that will show a record of students using the bus service. I have successfully managed to do so when a Bus Number is entered. It displays the list of all students that are using that Bus. The problem, however, is when I select Option that says "All Bus Records". What I need to do is, display the record of students in one bus and for the next bus number, it should move to the next page. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Is ForcePageBreak property used or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `BusNumber` field in the `GroupHeader` section and set `ForcePageBreak` to `rptPageBreakAfter` in the `GroupFooter` section

Answer (score 0):

In your problem. I would suggest **"Increasing of your Top or Bottom Margin"**
and change these Properties to proceed to Next Page:

```
PageHeader = KeepTogether = True
DetailSection = KeepTogether = True
PageFooter = ForcePageBreak = 2(ForcePageBreakAfter)
```

([My Sample VB6 File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YqbfYJBHMF6QMLys02UbYr7hfxTbXudu/view?usp=sharing))